# Why is "sip" missing when I run bzr?

Tags: qt, bazaar

When I run a bzr command such as:

```
bzr config launchpad_username
```

I get a strange error message:

```
Unable to load plugin 'qbrz' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/breezy/plugins/qbrz': No module named 'sip'
```

I can see that **/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/breezy/plugins/qbrz/__init__.py** contains:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)
```

The error message seems harmless, but it's annoying. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing [sip](https://pypi.org/project/sip/), a library for binding Python and C or C++ modules, often used with Qt. The fact that it isn't installed is probably a packaging error. You can install it manually with:

```
sudo apt install python3-sip
```

The error message should no longer appear.